# Expo React Native app crashes on Android but works in Expo Go

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I'm previewing my app in the Expo Go application everything works just fine, but when I build the android APK everything works great until I try to load the screen which contains the MapView.
When I go to that page the app crashes without telling me what's wrong

This is the MapView:

```
<MapView
    ref={map}
    style={styles.map}
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    initialRegion={location}
    pitchEnabled={false}
    userLocationUpdateInterval={3000}
    userLocationPriority="balanced"
    toolbarEnabled={false}
    tintColor="#00B4B4"
    customMapStyle={customMapStyle}
/>
```

btw, I have no Idea how to see the crash log if there is any log(I'd love to know how to see it)

Comment: You can view the crash log using [Logcat command-line tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat), simply run `adb logcat *:W` in terminal. W flag will show all logs with warning or higher priority, you should only look for the crash log of your app. We will try to help you if you can add the crash log to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add Google Maps Api key. In expo go, expo has their own Google Maps Api key, but when you build your own apk you need to add your own.Check this from expo docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#deploying-google-maps-to-an-android-standalone

Comment: como se agrega la key?